# Angular Material Mat-error Showing error for valid inputs, while validating with regex

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-error

Creating a signup form using angular material, It is displaying errors even if there is no error.

For a valid input it is displaying the error Invalid Input.
I've removed that mat-error condition the field is turning red while entering data.

***The status inside the control is showing the field is valid on submit.***

[image]

The error conditions are in in global constants file.
-Global const ts

```js
export class globalConstants{
public static genericErr:string="Someting wnet wrong,Please try again";
public static usrname:string='[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*';
}
```

HTML-

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex>
 <mat-label>User Name</mat-label>
<input matInput formControlName="usrname" required>
<mat-error *ngif="signUpForm.controls.usrname.touched && signUpForm.controls.usrename.invalid">
<span *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.usrname.errors.required">User Name is Mandatory</span>
<span *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.usrname.errors.pattern">Ivalid Input</span>
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>}
```

Signup Ts File:

```js
import { globalConstants } from '../shared/globalConst';
signUpForm: any = FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.signUpForm = this.formBuilder.group({usrname: ['Enter Username', [Validators.required,  Validators.pattern(globalConstants.usrname)]],
```

Kindly assist with your expertise.

Comment: Weird behavior. But there are some errors in your code, in HTML your formControlName is `usrename` while in component the control name was `usrname`. You will get the error for form control: `usrename` doesn't exist in from group. While `Validators.patternpattern` is incorrect as well. Please review, test and correct your code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun That errors happened while copy and paste, I've edited it. Still giving the same issue. Can you pls suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following code

> input-error-state-matcher.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroupDirective,
  NgForm,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Input with a custom ErrorStateMatcher */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-error-state-matcher-example',
  templateUrl: './input-error-state-matcher-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-error-state-matcher-example.css'],
})
export class InputErrorStateMatcherExample {
  userAddressValidations: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userAddressValidations = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(4),
          Validators.maxLength(20),
          Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]+'),
        ],
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

> input-error-state-matcher.html

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="userAddressValidations">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName">
    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
      First Name is Required!
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('minlength')">
      First Name should be atleast 4 characters long!
    </mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('maxlength')">
      First Name can be atmax n characters long!
    </mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="userAddressValidations.get('firstName').hasError('pattern')">
      First Name must follow this pattern!
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

[working example is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-validation-eg-fj5vf2?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html)

Comment: This validation will work, Thanks, could you please suggest the changes in my snippet using globalcont.ts file?

Comment: please check my stackblitz now. Thank you